# I found a question with what seems like a bad answer, I'm not an expert, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm trying to figure out the scientific merits of Sensory processing sensitivity/Higly sensitive person, because my SO thinks she has it. Skeptics has one question on the topic so far.

[Highly Sensitive Person Scale](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/highly-sensitive-person-scale/5070#5070)

The most upvoted answer is initially wrong, assuming it's the same thing as the introvert/extrovert personality scale and later updated with a more correct answer, but still keeping the incorrect info at the top.

The question in is referring to a specific website where self-tests are available. Those tests seem to be based on research done by Aron and Aron (1997), in the updated answer, another paper is cited "The Highly Sensitive Person: Stress and phsyical symptom reports" As far as I can understand, that research created another test, that is testing for more variables.

Here is a summary of the different measures: http://www.sicotests.com/psyarticle.asp?id=202

I'm not a psychologist nor a researcher and am just trying to figure out the merits of these claims. Can I do anything to help clean up this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without judging whether the first part is wrong, I notice that it's not really supported by the evidence presented. Yes, there is a link but it does not support the author's speculation.

Feel free to edit out the first part. The second part is well referenced and it should stay.